# My question is about names of the institution where in some new words are coined and used?

Tags: word-usage

I came across 2 signboards at 'the English Speaking Tutorials'. The names are SPEAKWELL ENGLISH and SPEAKON ENGLISH. Such words dont exist in dictionary or in usage.Are such usages appropriate?  can we lable such usage by any such names?

Comment: Could you [edit] your post and provide a link?

Comment: If, as you say, those are names, then it's fine. With names, anything goes. It's not clear what you mean by your last sentence: label such usage as what?

Comment: by labeling I mean the way we have different language features as 'contracted forms' , block language ,omission  etc Can we lable or name such coining of the words and phrases?

Comment: Oh, you're asking us to label such a coining. Well, I'd just call it a *name*, haha. They made up a name. This would otherwise be called a *compound* (and the process *compounding*) because *speak* and *well* are already words in their own right (this isn't a very accurate definition). Also, the words have been *concatenated* (made into a chain) into a single orthographic unit.